# D3 js BoxPlot with already calculated data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to make a D3 BoxPlot. 
I have a dataset with several billions of rows, and it is unfeasible to send the raw data to the client. So, I created an API and I send only the summarized version containing the max/min/std_dev values of each column.

In all the examples ( [one](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502) [two](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502) ) I saw using D3 BoxPlot, the data summarization is done on the client side (the opposite of my case).

Is it possible to use the BoxPlot with already calculated data? Does anyone have an example?

Comment: If the data comes summarised, with the 1st, 2nd and 3rd quartiles, it's even easier! Please post an example of your data structure.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado My data structure is like this:
[{"count": "2", "min": "3.6", "max": "4.6", "label": "labelA", "stddev": "0.72", "mean": "4.1"},{"count": "2", "min": "3.6", "max": "4.6", "label": "labelB", "stddev": "0.72", "mean": "4.1"},{"count": "2", "min": "3.6", "max": "4.6", "label": "labelC", "stddev": "0.72", "mean": "4.1"}]

Comment: Ok, I'm writing an answer... I suppose "min" is the first quartile and "max" is the third quartile. I don't see the median, so I'll use "mean".

Comment: You can pretty much insert any field in the json, as long it is precalculated...  So -> no problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since you are getting the already calculated data, the task here is even easier!

First, let's set the scales. In the data you copy/pasted in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281482/d3-js-boxplot-with-already-calculated-data?noredirect=1#comment73713877_43281482) you have `max` and `min`, which I'll use for the third and first quartiles. Since you don't have the second quartile (median) in your data, I'll use `mean`. Also, as your data have 3 identical objects, I change it a little bit, to make the boxes different.

So, setting the y scale:

```
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.max
    }) * 1.1])
    .range([h - padding, padding]);
```

Which is a standard linear scale.

For the x scale, I'm using a band scale:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.label
    }))
    .range([padding, w - padding])
    .padding(0.4);
```

Which is very good to give us the left and right limits of the rectangles.

Now, it's just a matter of printing the rectangles and the lines (the medians).

For the rectangles, notice the math to get the third quartile as the top of the rectangle, and the first quartile as its height (`y` and `height` attributes):

```
var boxes = svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.label)
    })
    .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.max)
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.min) - yScale(d.max)
    });
```

And, finally, for the lines, we just use `mean` for both `y1` and `y2` values:

```
var lines = svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 4)
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.label)
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.label) + xScale.bandwidth()
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.mean)
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.mean)
    })
```

Here is a demo with your data structure:

```js
var data = [{
  "count": "2",
  "min": "1.6",
  "max": "4.1",
  "label": "labelA",
  "stddev": "0.72",
  "mean": "3.1"
}, {
  "count": "2",
  "min": "1.1",
  "max": "2.9",
  "label": "labelB",
  "stddev": "0.72",
  "mean": "2.2"
}, {
  "count": "2",
  "min": "2.4",
  "max": "3.6",
  "label": "labelC",
  "stddev": "0.72",
  "mean": "2.7"
}];

var w = 500,
  h = 200,
  padding = 30,
  padding2 = 20;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.max
  }) * 1.1])
  .range([h - padding2, 10]);

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.label
  }))
  .range([padding, w - padding])
  .padding(0.4);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding2) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

var gY = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis);

var boxes = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.label)
  })
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.max)
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.min) - yScale(d.max)
  });

var lines = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", 4)
  .attr("x1", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.label)
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.label) + xScale.bandwidth()
  })
  .attr("y1", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.mean)
  })
  .attr("y2", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.mean)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

PS: Once you have the data for the whiskers, you can simply add the code for creating the lines to this basic structure, following the same principle.

Comment: Perfect... This is the spirit of stack overflow!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a boxplot rendering component as part of d3fc:

https://d3fc.io/api/series-api.html#boxplot

You can use this to render data that has already been 'summarised'

(Full disclosure: I'm one of the authors of d3fc)

Comment: Had some problems plotting the sample chart...  Invalid randomNormal function. Probably incompatibility issues with d3 version..  I will try again later on.